# The difference between Management and Configuration Policies

Tags: network, password-management, password-policy, risk-management, configuration

I am trying to find out the difference between **management** and **configuration** policies. Kindly, can someone elaborate that or showing an example so that I can understand each case.

Comment: Where are you seeing the two terms used? Context would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking specifically about password management and configuration?

> **Management** is outward facing and influences user behaviour such as '*password length*' or '*frequency of password change*' and typically relies on governance and policy; whereas
>
> **Configuration** is inward facing and influences service behaviour such as '*where passwords are kept*' (such as LDAP, or flat text files) or '*what authentication service is used to authenticate*' and typically relies on technical requirements and administrative choice.